# OpenGL Shadar Language in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm learning OpenGL through a great book that uses OpenGL version 3.3 in the Premake 4 plataform, but I actually want to learn OpenGL for Android, which supports OpenGL version 2.0. It's pretty much the same, as the concepts are the same, but I'm having some trouble with the Shader Language code.

For example, in the book the autor implements a Vertex Shader with the code:

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

void main(){
  gl_Position = position;
}
```

After a lot of research I was able to implement this exactly Vertex Shader code in Android with the code:

```
String vertexShaderCode =
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_Position = vPosition;" +
        "}";
```

But I can't figure out how can I implement this Vertex Shader below:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;

smooth out vec4 theColor;

void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
  theColor = color;
}
```

The book is http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tut02%20Vertex%20Attributes.html

Comment: You should learn about OpenGL-ES if you want to make apps using OpenGL capabilities. OpenGL and OpenGL-ES isn't the exact 100% same thing, though most of the function does and are named the same.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot implement the shader as it is written in OpenGL ES 2.0. This shader is written against the OpenGL 3.3 GLSL specification, OpenGL ES 2.0 uses syntax roughly equivalent to GLSL 120 (OpenGL 2.1).

- The `smooth` qualifier is used to control interpolation between shader stages, GLSL ES does not support this, all vertex shader outputs are smoothly interpolated in GLSL ES.
- `layout (...)` is unsupported by GLSL ES, you must use `glBindAttribLocation (...)` to set the location.
- `in` and `out` are not supported by GLSL ES, you must use `attribute` for vertex shader inputs and `varying` for vertex shader outputs and fragment shader inputs.

And last, `#version 330` is invalid. In OpenGL ES 2.0, there is only one GLSL ES specification, version 1.0 (so a compliant OpenGL ES 2.0 shader should begin with `#version 100`).

#### To answer your question about implementing that particular vertex shader:

```
#version 100

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 color;

varying   vec4 theColor;

void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
  theColor    = color;
}
```

This is of course only half of the equation, you need to pair it with a fragment shader that also uses OpenGL ES 2.0-compliant syntax.

#### A minimal fragment shader that would work with this vertex shader:

```
#version 100

varying vec4 theColor; // In GLSL 330 this would be written as: in vec4 theColor;

void main (void) {
  gl_FragColor = theColor;
}
```